# how to submit combo box value with out form using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I need to submit combo box value with out form. When I click on any value of combo that suppose to submit automatically using javascript. I am using PHP in backend.

```
<select name="select" id="select" style="width:50px;">
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="All">All</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I would imagine you need the [`change` handler](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html).

Comment: Are you using any javascript library like prototype or jQuery?

Comment: Have you written any javascript yet for the page? If so, then please include it in the Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a js part:

```
function getinfo() {
  var aList = document.getElementById("select");
  var val = aList.options[aList.selectedIndex].value;

  // document.write("<p>Here what you select: "+val+"</p>");
  // here you can send `val` to the server using... are you using any js library?
}
```

And you need to change your `select` declaration:

```
<select name="select" id="select" style="width:50px;" onchange="getinfo()">
                                                      --------------------
</select>
```

OK, how to send `val` to the server is another question... If you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) - you can use `jQuery.ajax(...)` or any helper like `jQuery.get(...)`. If you are vanilla-js user you can use [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) way and if you use any other lib - just check this lib's documentation to get helped about sending data to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the methods below.

1) Use Session or Cookie to send external data

2) Send a POST request using XMLHttpRequest in javascript.Checkout the link [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp).

3)You can use cURL function to send HTTP POST request. Please go through the link [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

- The `select` element should always be inside a `form.` But you don't need to expose the form on the page--you do not need to include a `submit` input element.
- You can use Javascript (JS) to submit the form after the user has changed the value of the select.
- Or you can use JS with Ajax to submit the form asynchronously in the background--the user will not be aware that the data had been submitted and the page will not reload or "flash"

What would you like to do?